# [GCP]Why can't I see the GPU selection button on my VM instance?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, gpu

I want to use GPU in Windows VM.
However, the GPU selection button is not active when creating the instance.
Currently, I applied for GPU(k-80) as a quota and got 1 allocation. Of course, I received mail.
Some of the answers asked me to check all regions, but all regions on the quota application page were disabled.

What's the problem?

[image: Disabled button]

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding the E2 instance type (as in your screenshot) cannot be paired with a GPU.

From the [machine types GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#gpus):

> You can attach GPUs to general-purpose N1 machine types or accelerator-optimized A2 machine types only. GPUs are not supported for other machine types.

Also consider the [regional availability of various GPU types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones).